# Не выводит текст EditText'а

Tags: android, java

Создал *AlertDialog*, в котором методом .setView добавляю layout с *EditText* и кнопками:

```
  AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(HomeActivity.this);
  View view = HomeActivity.this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.text_fields, null);
```

В этом же layout на одну из кнопок вешаю событие, которое должно брать значение *EditText*.  
Код кнопки:

```
    LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(HomeActivity.this);
    View view = factory.inflate(R.layout.text_fields, null);
    EditText text = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.editText);
    System.out.println("Text of view: " + text.getText());
```

Выводит либо дефолтное значение *EditText*, если оно установлено, либо пустоту, несмотря на то, что сам *EditText* заполнен.  
Также если прописать

```
    text.setText("some text");
```

то выводит some text.

Почему при нажатии на кнопку не выводится значение *EditText*?

*upd*
Если проделать эти манипуляции, но без Inflate и установкой `setViewContent(R.layout.text_fields)`, то все выводится. То есть, полагаю, проблема в том, что ID *EditText*, созданного в *AlertDialog.Builder*, отсутствует.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, у вас там, где

> Код кнопки:

нет кода кнопки. Там текстовое поле. И еще я не уверен, что команда `System.out.println` верное решение... Покажите код обработчика, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Я всегда так делаю:

```
text.getText().toString()
```

Comment: Да я делал так же. Проблема была в том, что текстовое поле находится в другом xml, в котором прописаны кнопки, на которых по онклику запускается определенный метод. В общем, просто убрал кнопки и сделал все действия в AlertDialog.